# How to pass function parameter value as key in JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

Assume I have the following function:

```
function create_unique_slug(database_slug_field, title) {
    var database_filter = {
        database_slug_field: title
    };
}
```

In this case, `database_filter` JSON object will contain key `database_slug_field` and its value will be the value of the passed parameter.

So, If I will call the function with the following input: `create_unique_slug('slug_awesome', 'my awesome title');`, JSON object will be the following:

```
{database_slug_field: 'my awesome title'}
```

What I want to achieve is get the JSON object as this:

```
{'slug_awesome': 'my awesome title'};
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: That's not  JSON it's an object literal.

Comment: yeah, it's `json`, not `JSON`, or maybe `j.s.o.n.` if you wanna be pedantic...

Comment: Well JSON is an acronym (Java Script Object Notation) and all acronyms are uppercased so JSON is correct. You say FBI not fbi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the modified function:

```
function create_unique_slug(database_slug_field, title) {
    var database_filter = {};
    database_filter[database_slug_field] = title;
    return database_filter;
}
```

If you want to print the object as JSON all you have to do is call JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use square brackets to tell javascript that you want to use the parameters value as key:

```
var database_filter = {};
database_filter[database_slug_field] = title;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
function create_unique_slug(database_slug_field, title) {
    var database_filter = {};
    database_filter[database_slug_field] = title;
}
```